# 'Specify by name and directory' and 'Specify by refenerce' not available

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I am new to Kettle. Please follow me to reproduce the problem

1. Create a Job and drag and drop a Transfation to the design panel
2. Right click the Transfation and click 'Edit job entity'
3. 'Specify by name and directory' and 'Specify by refenerce' not available in Transformation specification tab

How to resolve this problem? Thanks

Sorry for my English.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As soon as you connect to a Kettle repository via the Tools menu these controls are enabled.

[answered by marabu from Pentaho forum](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?149895-Specify-by-name-and-directory-and-Specify-by-refenerce-not-available&p=353993&posted=1#post353993)